# Переопределение метода экземпляра класса

Tags: java, классы, методы

Мне нужно переопределить метод класса Button

```
public class Button { 
    public void action(){} 
}
```

Я пробовал инициализировать так:

```
Button home = new Button(){
    public void action() {
        // TODO some code
    }
}
```

Но ничего не получилось. Нужна помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но ничего не получилось.

А в чем заключается это «не получилось»? Если при вызове переопределенного метода Вы получаете `cannot resolve method`, то, может быть, Вы импортировали вовсе не Ваш класс `Button`, а одноименный класс из другого пакета, который данного метода не имеет?

При создании экземпляра некоторого класса Вы можете переопределить его методы, в итоге получите анонимный класс (а точнее, субкласс).

Пример:

```
class Button {
    public void action() {
        System.out.println("Basic implementation");
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Button button = new Button() {
            @Override
            public void action() {
                System.out.println("Overridden implementation");
            }
        };

        button.action();
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
Overridden implementation
```

Если же класс с переопределенными методами будет использован многократно, то целесообразно создать именованный класс.

Answer (score 2):

Наследование никто не отменял.

```
public class MyButton extends Button {
    @Override
    public void action(){
        // переопределённая логика тут
    }
}

Button home = new MyButton();
```

Comment: А нельзя без наследования обойтись? У меня таких кнопок будет сотни.

Comment: @ДенисСунагатов А для чего вам вообще наследование в таком случае?

Answer (score 1):

Вижу 3 способа решить проблему:

1) Классический способ через переопределение - как указано в ответе коллег по цеху (например @АндрейБогатов)

2) Через переопределение слушателя `action()` (очевидно, класс `Button` должен иметь слушателя что-то типа `setOnActionListener()` с соответствующим интерфейсом `OnActionListener`) - к сожалению ТС не дал ссылку на оригинальный класс `Button` - иначе я бы написал пример

3) Путь героя - написать собственный `ClassLoader`, который в рантайме загружает нужный class, что то типа (но это уже мозговой вывих, который применяется крайне редко):

```
class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

     public Class findClass(String name) {
         byte[] b = loadClassData(name);
         return defineClass(...);
     }

     private byte[] loadClassData(String name) {
         // загрузчик класса в вашей имплементации
          . . .
     }
 }
```

Comment: Класс button не из пакетов swing или awt, это мой собственный класс. Поэтому там нет листенеров.

Comment: Ну допишите к нему листенер - проблем то :)